# SQL query error or missing database shows syntax error using LIKE query

Tags: sqlite, kotlin

I have a syntax error that I don't know how to solve. Here is the code:

```
fun allSearchData(searchStringRaw: String): Cursor{
    val searchString = "% $searchStringRaw %"
    val query = "Select * from $MARKER_TABLE where $KEY_NAME like $searchString"
    val c = mySpotsDatabase!!.rawQuery(query, null)
    c.moveToFirst()
    return c
}
```

and it is giving me this error:

```
 Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (near "%": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from my_locations_table where Name like % h %)
```

If I remove the spaces as follows it makes no difference.

```
val searchString = "%$searchStringRaw%"
```

and this just changes the error line to the following, so I know its not the space in the string issue.

```
 (near "%": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from my_locations_table where Name like %h%)
```

I can not see the syntax error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the argument for the LIKE clause in single quotes.

e.g. `val searchString = "'% $searchStringRaw %'"`

However, you would be better of using the second parameter of the **rawQuery** method to pass the arguments, in which case they will be properly escaped and you gain the advantage of protecting against SQL Injection.

Comment: Is there a need to handle SQL injection as its the user's own offline database with only their data?  Only the user will use it on their device.

Comment: @timv not really essential. However, there is the potential that the use, if they input the search value, that they could inadvertently do damage. As such it's recommend to pass arguments so they are escaped.

Comment: agreed, working on code now and will update answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To @MikeT who saw the issue.
Here is the correct code:

```
fun allSearchData(searchStringRaw: String): Cursor{
    val searchString = "'%$searchStringRaw%'"
    val query = "Select * from $MARKER_TABLE where $KEY_NAME like $searchString"
    val c = mySpotsDatabase!!.rawQuery(query, null)
    c.moveToFirst()
    return c
}
```

It now works perfectly